# ¿Cuando puedo Usar Linq y Cuando Usar Sql?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Tengo una serie de dudas sobre cuándo emplear cada una de estas, me ayudaria mucho saber sus experiencias

Comment: Son cosas completamente distintas

Comment: Favor leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ventaja de usar LINQ es que tienes consultas fuertemente tipadas (strongly typed), debido a que las clases que se generan deben coincidir con el esquema de tu base de datos, esto significa, que cuando haces una consulta utilizando LINQ puedes obtener una ventana que te muestra las opciones permitidas para tu
consulta, es lo que se llama 'intellisense', lo cual facilita enormente la programación y te evita errores de tipo.

Answer (score 0):

SQL es un lenguaje para la consulta de base de datos, puedes crear tablas, procedimientos, vistas, etc etc. Lo importante aquí es que **SQL es del lado de las bases de datos**.

Por el contrario **Linq es un Framework/herramienta de .Net que te ayuda a trabajar/procesar colecciones de objetos de manera sencilla**, en lugar de realizar alguna operacion de uno por uno, te deja hacerlo en conjunto. Pero esto del lado de .Net, ya sea que estes en web, escritorio o móvil.

Ahora tambien cabe recalcar que exiten herramientas como  [Linq to Sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) o como [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/overview) que te ayudan a procesar informacion en la base de datos usando Linq en tu lenguaje de .Net, lo que hacen internamente es que transforman tu código Linq en consultas SQL.